# Recycling bin folders turn into files?

Tags: windows, windows-10, recycle-bin, files-folders

What does this mean? When I try to delete folders in recycling bin, this is what I get, and I can't delete them:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you recently ran chkdsk on your drive? Any event it appears your deleted files have become orphaned files, which is probably fine, since the files are deleted.  However, it’s also a sign, your HDD has bad sectors (enough that  you probably should replace your drive).

Comment: It looks like your recycle bin is corrupt. That can happen. To restore, you need to delete the folder and let windows recreate it. That does mean that you lose all the files still in there

Comment: This is a freshly built pc... I don't need to replace the SSD. I think it was just a glitch because when I next opened recycling bin, the problem was fixed.